# SQL Server: Is there a way to grant execute using GUI?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

Is there a way to grant execute permissions for a role or a user using GUI (not T-SQL)? I'm using SQL Server 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [**Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx).

It is part of the SQL Server Client Tools package but there's also a free version called [**Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en).

Related resources:

- [How to grant Permissions on a Stored Procedure (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345484.aspx)
- [Permissions (SQL Server Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I was looking for this (found from your link): 

"You cannot use SQL Server Management Studio to grant permissions on system stored procedures or system functions. Use GRANT Object Permissions instead."

Answer (score 9):

#### Yes, there is a way. Use *Permissions* page of *Database Properties* window.

Once database properties windows is displayed, follow steps `1`-`4` and press `OK`.

Using steps `A`, `B` you can verify it is creating exactly the expected `GRANT EXECUTE TO` command.

[image]